# Print Date in c# in a specified format

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am using the .NET `DateTime` type and would like to print date in the following format

> "2017-08-23T11:33:14.653191-05:00"

I am currently able to get the date with year month and day by using this.

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

The above code results in "2017-08-23", but I want the date in above format.

Comment: Have you tried `ToString` or `String.Format` with date formatting?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: I am getting date with year month and day by using this : DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"). But how to get the remaining part?

Comment: What is the -05:00 here?

Comment: I think you want this format `dateTime.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK")` which will print date like this `2007-07-21T15:11:19.1250000+05:30`

Comment: @WillyDavidJr: may be `GMT`

Comment: Thank you @mmushtaq `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK")` this worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a custom format string to achieve this by using DateTime Now with a format

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffK");
```

Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). Parts of the format string are:

- `yyyy` is the four digit year
- `MM` the month (numerical)
- `dd` the days of the month
- `HH` the hours (24 hours format)
- `ss` the seconds
- `ffffff` the millionths of a second
- `K` the time zone

Comment: DateTime with UtcNow returned me ""2017-08-23T06:21:39.479692Z"" but by using DateTime Now this way: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffK")` gave me the expected result : "2017-08-23T11:52:34.437124+05:30". Thank you  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use date formatting like:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime("your_date_value");
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

date1.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFFFFK", ci);
```

See [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: This will omit trailing zeros in the millionths of a second part.

Answer (score 1):

use it like

```
 DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffff‌​K")
```